# Indenting headings in org-mode

Tags: org-mode

When I convert an organization-style file (one with many headings and only brief paragraphs)

```
#+OPTIONS: toc:1
#+LATEX_CLASS: article
#+LATEX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [letterpaper]
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{fullpage}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{times}

#+title: Produce
#+author: Me
#+date: 2023-02-17

* North America
** Fruits
*** Durian
Lorem ipsum dolor
*** Jackfruit
Lorem ipsum dolor
*** Lychee
Lorem ipsum dolor
** Vegetables
*** Celeriac
Lorem ipsum dolor
*** Kohlrabi
Lorem ipsum dolor
*** Oka
Lorem ipsum dolor
```

to either PDF

[image: PDF output]

or to HTML

[image: HTML output]

the output is hard to read, on account of the lack of indentation of sections and subsections.

What is a good solution to this problem? A one-shot-two-birds solution that works for both PDF and HTML would be fantastic, but it feels too ambitious.

Otherwise, am I on my own going back to writing CSS that never looks terribly good or hunting among 1001 LaTeX packages for one that provides a nice look?

Can you suggest a brief, nice solution—even one for just one of the two outputs? (It's not too hard to convert from HTML to LaTeX.)

Comment: "... am I on my own going back to writing CSS ... or hunting among 1001 LaTeX packages ...?" ---  I suspect so. You might try the TeX SE for suggestions. I'm not sure where CSS questions should go. It might be easier to go a different way to break the monotony: leave the headings alone and indent the paragraph. For LaTeX, you can use the `indentfirst` package with `#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{indentfirst}`.To do a similar thing with CSS, add `#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <style> p { text-indent: 2em; } </style>`. That visually separates the subsections, so it's easier to parse.

Comment: @NickD That's probably as good as it gets at present. Please either move your comment to be an answer, or else I can simply delete the question.